# Bootstrap Popover, .click not catching button inside popover

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

First off, a fiddle of the problem: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/timotheus/jjYQp/4/)

I am using a popover, and it's content is html, a button with class "click_me". I have jquery to listen for a click on "click_me" and it should throw an alert. However, it doesn't. Am I missing something?

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.demo_button').click(function () {
    $(this).popover({
                html: true,
                trigger: 'manual',
                placement: 'right',
                content: function () {
                    var $buttons = $('#popover_template').html();
                    return $buttons;
                }
    }).popover('toggle');
});

$('.click_me').click(function() {
    alert('it works!');
});

});
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary demo_button">Click here</button>

<div id="popover_template">
    <button class="btn click_me">Make Alert</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

.click() will only work for elements that are present on load you need to use on()

```
$(document).on("click", ".click_me", function() {
    alert('it works!');
});
```

Comment: I wasn't thinking about the fact it wasn't created on load. Thanks, this is a perfect answer!

Comment: @stefan - I have similar situation and wanted to ask you more on this. i have $(document).ready(function () {}); already and i am using above code for click event inside it and it's working perfectly fine but just to clear the concept: we have  $(document).ready(function () {}); and why we still need to attach $(document) with click event ? is it fair to use that way ?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is you're attaching an event to an element that isn't ready to receive that event. You should attach the event to a parent element, then you can filter for the element. This way it doesn't matter when your clickable element shows up, it will work.

```
<div class="container"><br />
    <button class="btn btn-primary demo_button">Click here</button>

    <div id="popover_template">
        <button class="btn click_me">Make Alert</button>
    </div>
</div>

 $('.container').on("click", ".click_me", function() {
     alert('it works!');
 });
```

Also when doing this, don't attach it to a parent that's too high up the tree. You want to attach it to the nearest possible parent element. We don't need to have a click event on something like `document` because it's a good idea to be specific of which elements will get this event. Attaching it to `document` will mean that any element, that has the class of `click_me`, will be click able and respond to the same code. If you want to have different functionality in different buttons, you can't, because they're all responding to the same code attached to `document`.

Btw here's your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjYQp/7/).

Comment: Though @stefan answer is broadly correct. This answer is more complete. This implementation is more efficient. Your script won't have to traverse the entire `document` to find the button.

Answer (score 2):

You should try the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.demo_button').click(function () {
        $(this).popover({
                html: true,
                trigger: 'manual',
                placement: 'right',
                content: function () {
                    var $buttons = $('#popover_template').html();
                    return $buttons;
                }
         }).popover('toggle');
         $('.click_me').off('click').on('click', function() {
             alert('it works!');
         });
    });
});
```

When the DOM is ready, you're button it's not yet created, doing this, everytime the popover rises you will handle the event on your created button.

Answer (score 0):

Use : 
show.bs.popover  - This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.

```
$('#myPopover').on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
  // bind your button click event here
})
```