# Call JS Function with onClick attribute within Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to call a JS function with an onClick attribute attached to a button within a Bootstrap popover like this :

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        trigger : 'click',
        content : '<center><button onClick="quickDelete();return false;" name="dltBtn" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-block"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-block stsBtn"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Status</button></center>'
      });
```

But when I click on the button :

> ReferenceError: quickDelete is not defined

I also done that :

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                trigger : 'click',
                content : '<center><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-block dltBtn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-block stsBtn"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Status</button></center>'
              });
$('.dltBtn').click(function() {
   alert('ok');
});
```

But nothing .. Can you help me maybe ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: where is quickDelete defined?

Comment: quickDelete is defined just above "$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Popover, .click not catching button inside popover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682267/bootstrap-popover-click-not-catching-button-inside-popover)